# How to get URL of product form website in powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I have website `https://www.shop-naturpur.de/index.php?lang=0&cl=search&searchparam=3283950923699#/q/3283950923699` I need to get product url from that site .

I need to get this product url site from powershell `https://www.shop-naturpur.de/Naturkosmetik/Koerperpflege/Cattier-Duschgel-Wilde-Verbena-Zitrus-1L.html`

I am using below code but no luck

```
$site=Invoke-WebRequest –Uri 'https://www.shop-naturpur.de/index.php?lang=0&cl=search&searchparam=3283950923699#/q/3283950923699'
$site.Links.Href | Sort-Object | Get-Unique

$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.shop-naturpur.de/index.php?lang=0&cl=search&searchparam=3283950923699#/q/3283950923699"
$WebResponse.Links | Select href
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get first a sessionID, then with this SessionID you can perform a search.

After that, you have to process the output from query.

```
$url = 'https://www.shop-naturpur.de/index.php?lang=0&cl=search&searchparam=3283950923699#/q/3283950923699' 
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable websession  |out-null
$sid=($websession.Cookies.GetCookies($url) | where {$_.name -eq "sid"}).Value
$req=Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://search.epoq.de/inbound-servletapi/getSearchResult?full&callback=e&tenantId=shop-naturpur-de&sessionId=$sid&format=json&query=3283950923699"
($req.Content.Substring(2,$req.Content.Length-4) | ConvertFrom-Json ).result.items.item.link.'$'
```

Comment: Thanks you very much you saved my time. I need one more help I need to get price from https://www.shop-naturpur.de/Naturkosmetik/Koerperpflege/Cattier-Duschgel-Wilde-Verbena-Zitrus-1L.html   web page , or can you please learn how to get value from this page.

Comment: `code`
($req.Content.Substring(2,$req.Content.Length-4) | ConvertFrom-Json ).result.items.item.'g:price'.'$'

Comment: Gyula Kokas, Can you please teach me how get any other parameter value from product page , It would help me a lot . Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Hello , how to get description and title from https://www.shop-naturpur.de/Naturkosmetik/Koerperpflege/Duschen/Sante-Feste-Happiness-Duschpflege.html

Comment: Gyula , Need your help , Would please teach me how to get any variable value.